# How do I correctly configure a Spring MVC webapp when using a java Configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC via a @Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    // more stuff
}
```

In my web.xml I create the ApplicationContext:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>my.package.WebConfiguration</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I also create a DispatcherServlet, as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mywebapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mywebapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In order to get the dispatcherServlet to work I need a mywebapp-servlet.xml  Right now, it's empty.  Do I actually need the mywebapp-servlet.xml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any XML file. But you must tell the Dispatcher to not look for the default file:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>my.pack.WebConfiguration</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mywebapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mywebapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Just for your information: in fact, in Servlet 3 web.xml is no longer required, too.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still on jetty 6.x, so no servlet 3 for me, yet.

Comment: @Jon: Ok. But have this answer resolved your issue? Please, accept it or tell me why not.

Comment: @Sinuehepop: I get 'custom WebApplicationContext class [my.package.WebConfiguration] is not of type ConfigurableWebApplicationContext'

Comment: @Jon: Ok, we missed ContextLoaderListener. Try it now.